# Why I am getting this?

Tags: c++

29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000478 at pc 0x0000003a5517 bp 0x7ffe2f5c2670 sp 0x7ffe2f5c2668

Here is my code:
class Solution {
public:
vector summaryRanges(vector& nums) {

```
    if(nums.size() == 0)
        return {};
    
    if(nums.size() == 1)
        return {to_string(nums[0])};
    
vector<string> ans{};
int i=0,j=1,initial=nums[0];
if(nums.empty()||nums.size()==0)
  return ans; 
while(j<=nums.size())
{
    if(i<nums.size())
    {
      if(nums[i]+1==nums[j])
      {
        i++;
        j++;
      }
     else
     {   
        string str3;
        if(initial!=nums[i])
         {   
            string str = to_string(initial);
            string str1= to_string(nums[i]);
            string str2 = "->";
            str3=str+str2+str1;
         }
        else
         {
           str3 = to_string(initial);
         }
         ans.push_back(str3);
         initial=nums[j];
            i=j;
            j++;    
      }
    }
    else
    {
        string str = to_string(initial);
        ans.push_back(str);
    } 
}
return ans;
}
```

};

Comment: You've dumped some code that is totally out of context and expect us to debug it for you. That's not how this site works. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages before you begin posting. I'd advise you to carefully read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I think you are accessing an index out of vector size . Index j is probably going out of bounds .

```
while(j< = nums.size())
```

and

```
nums[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
while(j<=nums.size())
```

and these

```
if(nums[i]+1==nums[j])
...
initial=nums[j];
```

look very suspicious. If `j == nums.size()` then `nums[j]` is an out of bounds error on `num`. Maybe you meant this?

```
while(j<nums.size())
```

(I.e. the same as you have with the `i` variable).